# finding the limit for a martingale

Tags: probability

I have trouble finding the exact limit for a martingale:

Let $\{\xi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Markov chain with $\xi_0$ uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and 
$$
P(\xi_{n+1}=\alpha\xi_n+(1-\alpha)|\xi_n)=\xi_n
$$
$$
P(\xi_{n+1}=\alpha\xi_n|\xi_n)=1-\xi_n,
$$
for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$.
It's clear that $\xi_n$ is a martingale and $\xi_n\leq1$ for all n, so by Martingale Convergence theorem $\xi_n$ have a almost surely limit $\xi$, which I'm trying to find . In Durrett's book, this kind of question normally ends when we see the stationary point by observation (if I'm not mistaken), while here it seems like $0$ and $1$ are both stable. How to get the almost surely limit formally? Thanks for any help.

Let me add some of my thoughts I just came up:
For those events always go left, the probability is $\prod(1-\xi_n)=\prod(1-\alpha^{n}\xi_0)$, which is convergent to a nonzero constant since $\xi_0\Sigma\alpha^{n}$ converges. That is to say, there is a positive possibility that $\xi_n$ converges to $0$. As $\xi_n$ converges to $\xi$ almost surely, it forces $\xi$ to be $0$.

Is my argument above correct? Please let me know if there are any problems in it. Thanks a lot.

As being pointed out, it's similar to the other question while I want to find the limit $\xi$. With the help of the other question, it can be seen that $P(\xi=0)=P(\xi=1)=1/2.$ I would guess $\xi=1_{(1/2,1]}$, but how to prove it formally?

Comment: Doob's forward convergence theorem doesn't give you a deterministic limit, so knowing positive probability that the limit is 0 doesn't prevent there also being positive probability that it's something else

Comment: What do you mean by "find the limit" and "guess $\xi= 1_{(1/2,1]}$"? For a general probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$, $\xi = 1_{(1/2,1]}$ is not even a random variable (it's not well-defined).

Comment: I'm sorry  for the improper expression. I just start self-learning probability and always confused with its space. Since $\xi_0$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, I just naively thought when the initial condition is larger than 1/2, it will go to 1 eventually. Is it enough to have the distribution when the question ask us to find the almost sure limit of $\xi_n$?